# Closures in javascript with different case

Tags: javascript

I have two different case below. Both case applies the same method javascript closure function. Case 2 output the result as expected but case 1 doesn't, as the increament stops at 1 every time the button is clicked. I know some other closure method to make it work as i expected or increase count every time the button is clicked. But i am just curious why the below case 1 doesn't work while having same method and same way as in case 2 which works though. I hope it makes sense.

case:1

```js
function incrementClickCount() {
  var clickCount = 0;

  function a() {
    return ++clickCount;
  }
  return a();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alert(incrementClickCount());">
```

case:2

```js
function addNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
  var returnValue = 'Result is : ';

  function add() {
    return returnValue + (firstNumber + secondNumber);
  }
  return add();
}

console.log(addNumber(10, 20));
```

Comment: Whose going to fall for it

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. They both output as expected. What is unusual/different about the output of case 1?

Comment: Every time you call `incrementClickCount` you reset `clickCount` to `0` and then increment it once.

Comment: @4castle in case 1 when the button is clicked many times the count doesn't increase, it just shows 1 every time.

Comment: That's because you do `var clickCount = 0` in the function. How do you expect it to increase if you keep setting it back to 0?

Comment: @srs I don't understand the comparison to case 2. Doesn't it always output 30? So what's the difference?

Comment: @4castle I am not comparing the cases, i just wanted to show that in both cases functions were called in the same way. yeah it always output 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the function `a` from the incrementClickCount function, at the moment you are returning `a()` i.e. the result of calling a.

```js
    function incrementClickCount(){
        var clickCount = 0;
        function a(){
            return ++clickCount;
        }
        return a;
    }

    var incrementer = incrementClickCount();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alert(incrementer())">
```

A more compact approach is to declare and return the function in one go, with ES6 lambda notation:

```
function incrementClickCount() {
    var clickCount = 0;
    return () => ++clickCount;
}
```

Another piece of advice would be to add a listener to the button rather than using the onclick attribute.  The benefits include encapsulating all behaviour within your Javascript, and being able to remove the listener if needed.

```js
function makeIncrementer() {
  var clicks = 0;
  return () => ++clicks;
}

const incrementer = makeIncrementer();

function clickHandler() {
  alert(incrementer());
}

document.getElementById('incrementButton').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

```html
<button id='incrementButton'>Increment</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the variable outside the function, so you don't keep resetting it back to 0.

```js
var clickCount = 0;

function incrementClickCount() {

  function a() {
    return ++clickCount;
  }
  return a();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alert(incrementClickCount());">
```

There's not much point in using the inner function in this case. You can simply write:

```
var clickCount = 0;
function incremenCount() {
    return ++clickCount;
}
```

Comment: I didn't wanted to make clickCount variable global.